# Keeps Update All Text And Not the selected text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code iam trying to make the text div under the image editable by using keyup and using .val() but iam having a problem when i click on another image and edit the textbox to update the new image text they all change.

```
$('.HeaderGifs').live('click', function() {
 var img_class = $(this).attr("class"); 
 var img_src = this.src;
  $('#img_prop').css("display","block");
  $('#pre_img').html("<img src='"+img_src+"'></img>");
  var image_sel_id = img_class.replace("HeaderGifs ", "")
 alert(image_sel_id);

    $('#alt_text').keyup(function() { 

    var alt_text = $(this).val(); 

    $('#text_'+image_sel_id).text(alt_text);

        });
});
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with every click you're binding a *new* [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) handler to `#alt_text`, so just [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the previous handler, like this:

```
$('#alt_text').unbind('keyup').keyup(function() {
  $('#text_'+image_sel_id).text($(this).val());
});
```

Or, a bit more efficient, just make `image_sel_id` a variable that changes and bind the `#alt_text` handler once...and it'll always point to the current image:

```
var image_sel_id;
$('.HeaderGifs').live('click', function() {
  $('#img_prop').css("display","block");
  $('#pre_img').html("<img src='"+this.src+"'></img>");
  image_sel_id = this.className.replace("HeaderGifs ", "")
}); 
$('#alt_text').keyup(function() {
  if(!image_sel_id) return; //one hasn't been clicked yet 
  $('#text_'+image_sel_id).text($(this).val());
});
```

Note the check in the `#alt_text` handler,  this is optional since `#text_` *probably* won't find anything, but might as well save some cost and not run the rest of the function at all since an image hasn't been clicked yet.